# Windwos bat svn command,met 'svn switch' does not support switching a working copy to different repository

Tags: android, svn

I meet this weird problem. Our team is making a mobile game. And we use Unreal Engine3. We put our project in svn. And now, we want to publish our game in different android mobile game store, just like Google Play etc. So we use svn to create some branches that contains android SDK part of our hole project.
Therefore, I want use Windows .bat file to switch code. My .bat code is like below:
svn switch http://192.181.80.142/svn/branches/sourcefold .\target folder
And I met this problem:
'svn switch' does not support switching a working copy to different repository
Thanks for your help.

Comment: So basically the error message says all that you need to know. What is your question then?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the command that you run is `svn switch http://192.181.80.142/svn/branches/sourcefold .\target`.

And the error received is:

```
'svn switch' does not support switching a working copy to different repository
```

The problem is that you were trying to switch the working copy to another repository`, not the repositories from which you checked out the working copy originally. You should take a closer look at your repositories and double-check the repository URL that you want to switch to.

Read SVNBook:

- [`svn switch` command line reference](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html)
- [Traversing Branches](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.switchwc.html)